# microsoft graph api which endpoint to use Net or Com

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

i have used the application available at https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant and made it as multi-tenant,

using the access token generated in this application i could list down and access the children on one drive for business, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children.

This application uses graph end point as https://graph.microsoft.net/ but i noticed that it doesn't work, then i started using https://graph.microsoft.com/

and it started working.

my question which is correct endpoint,https://graph.microsoft.net/ or https://graph.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 2):

https://graph.microsoft.com/ is the correct endpoint.
Please see docs at http://graph.microsoft.io, including graph explorer which lets you explore and try out the API

Comment: do you know why the other one is used for

Comment: It's also using graph.windows.net, (rather than graph.microsoft.net) which is the Azure Active Directory Graph, an older API also used to get data about users and groups and largely superceded by the Microsoft Graph as @Dan says above.